# HealthCheck for the containers running in the Azure Linux App service

Tags: linux, azure, containers

I'm trying to monitor the health of the containers under the Linux App service, So, is there is any way to do the in Azure.
I found a document https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Health-Check-(Preview) , but this is only for Windows. Any other better way to perform the monitoring .

Thanks

Comment: you'll need to do it by yourself. Here's some useful link: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio , sorry I forget to mention that my app is in NodeJS

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Azure Application Insights, URL ping test.

Azure Application Insights can send web requests to your application at regular intervals. It can alert you if your application isn't responding, or if it responds too slowly.

You can set up availability tests for any HTTP or HTTPS endpoint that is accessible from the public internet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28602010)

Comment: @MathewHD: Based on the edit, this is more than just a link.